# how to make Hive column in lowercase compatible to tableau dashboard columns in uppercase

Tags: hive, tableau-api, cloudera

I have cloudera hive table whose column names are in lowercase.This table is being used in a 22 dashboards in tableau where the column names are in upper /camelcase. 
I cant change the case for each dashboard neither can convert hive table's column name to uppercase. 
Do we have some setting in tableau where the case can be ignored?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why this is a problem. Please edit your question with some more detail, including any error messages you get when you open your Tableau workbook..

Comment: I have tried to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename field name in tableau. (attached screenshot)

After doing this you have to change aliases on each workbook or dashboard as per your requirement.

I hope this will work for you.

[image: Rename field name]